# Session has different elements after reload a page?

Tags: php, arrays, session

page1:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['allCaps']=array("img01.png", "img02.png"...);  // 20 images
```

page2:

```
shuffle($_SESSION['allCaps']);
$_SESSION['fiveCaps'] = array_slice($_SESSION['allCaps'], 0, 5);
foreach ($_SESSION['fiveCaps'] as $key=>$val)
echo $key." ".$val;   // result - five img.names - remember this
```

page3:

```
session_start();
shuffle($_SESSION['fiveCaps']);
foreach ($_SESSION['fiveCaps'] as $key=>$val)
echo $key." ".$val;   // result - five img. names - remember this
```

I excpect the two results allways to be the same, of course except the ordering the elements (because of shuffle on page3).
But sometimes the results are the same, sometimes (after reloading page3) - are not
On page3 appear the elements which don't exist on page2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from page 3:

```
session_start();
```

Also, be aware sometimes sessions get lost, because the web server was restarted.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and found no problem. I guess it is because you are starting the session again on page 3. Remove line:

```
session_start();
```

on page 3 and pls let me know if it works. :)

Comment: Isn't session_start() supposed to resume an existing session if it already exists?

Comment: @Barmar: Seems so after I checked the reference. But while I tried removed that line, the code works. While you are state the line twice, the PHP will return a notice: `Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in ...`.

Comment: You could do: `if (!session_id()) session_start();`